# Spark Streaming reading data from only one kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application , I have to subscribe to multiple topics to read and process data. Now to test I have added two topics.
But I the following code is reading data from only one topic. I have tried sending data from a custom code and also through Kafka consumer batch files. If I cerate multiple direct streams one for each topic then I am able to read from all topics. But I have 1000's of topics so I want to create only one direct stream and provide a topic set. Anyone has Idea what I might be doing wrong ?

```
Collection<String> topicList = new ArrayList<>();   
topicList.add("A");
topicList.add("B");
final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    streamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<
                    String, String> Subscribe(topicList, kafkaParams));

for(String topic:topicList)
{
    JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> filteredStreams = stream.filter(msg -> {
        return msg.topic().equals(topic);
    });

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> kafkaMessages = filteredStreams.mapToPair(new KafkaConsumerFunction());
    process(kafkaMessages );
}
```

Comment: What version of spark you are using?

Comment: did you get any solution for it?